# how can i run "sudo -i' without truncating my .bash_history?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I want the same bash history for sudo as my normal user so I symlinked my local user to the /root/ dir. For whatever reason when I run "`sudo -i`" it truncates my bash history file to 1998 lines.
Here are my env variables for my user account:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups  
HISTSIZE=100000  
PROMPT_COMMAND=history -a; history -c; history -r  
HISTFILESIZE=100000
```

and for my root account:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
HISTSIZE=100000
PROMPT_COMMAND=history -a; history -c; history -r
HISTFILESIZE=100000
```

Any way I can prevent this truncation? thanks

Comment: What you are doing here sounds like a bad idea to me.  The information associated with root is separated for a reason.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I know the risks thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by symlinking the other dotfiles:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Mar 27 08:03 .bash_history -> /home/dewi/.bash_history
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Mar 30 09:22 .bash_profile -> /home/dewi/.bash_profile
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   18 Mar 30 09:23 .bashrc -> /home/dewi/.bashrc
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   19 Mar 30 09:23 .profile -> /home/dewi/.profile
```

Maybe previously it did not work something was not being set early enough before it decided to truncate the bash history file